# Clarification of Rouche's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Rouche's theorem: Suppose $f,g$ are analytic inside and on a regular closed curve $\gamma$ and that $|f| > |g|$ for all $z\in \gamma$, then $\mathbb{Z}(f+g)=\mathbb{Z}(f)$ **inside** $\gamma$, where $\mathbb{Z}(f)$ is the number of zeros of $f$.

**My question is**: What about the zeros of $f$ and $g+f$ **on** $\gamma$?

Comment: $f$ can't have any zeros on $\gamma$, because $|f| > |g| \ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you! Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: Not really, since it's just a one-liner from me. You're of course welcome to post an answer to your own question and accept it (and I'd suggest expanding the answer just a little bit).